Movie about a murderous aunt and uncle
This was an American movie from the late 1990s. 
It was about a girl (around 15) and a boy (around 10). Their parents had died in a car accident so they moved in with their uncle and aunt. They later found out that the uncle and aunt killed their parents. Later in the film, the uncle and aunt tried killing them too.  
The house they moved in was big, modern and had a pool. There was also a scene where the aunt was lying on a couch with a needle in her arm, which she later said was a insulin because she was diabetic. 

This sounds like 2001's The Glass House:

When Ruby Baker's parents are killed in a car accident, she and her brother, Rhett, must travel to Malibu, to live with Terrence and Erin Glass, their former neighbors. At first, all seems well. Ruby is making new friends at school and Rhett is getting more video games and flashy toys than he's ever had in his life. When Ruby speaks to her family's estate lawyer, he tells her that her parents have left Rhett and her $4 million. Suddenly, Ruby begins to notice odd behavior from Terry and Erin.

It has two kids, an older sister and a younger brother, with killed parents, moving into a rather modern house to live with new parents, which they become increasingly suspicious of.
Also, there's this scene:

Ruby comes across unlabeled pharmaceuticals and sees Erin injecting
  herself, though the couple claim this is for diabetes.


+1: May not be what OP wants, but enough details fit to make this a viable answer given the description.

Darn beat me to it.  :P

@TrishLing I knew this wouldn't stay unanswered for long.

Try answering my other question Trish :D
